# Display the maximum and the minimum of a row of numbers the ending signal is a 0

Tags: c, if-statement, numbers, max, min

I've found a French exercise online. This is a translation of the wording:

> Write a program to display the maximum and the minimum of a row of integers (the row is one or more inputs by the user). The inputs aren't kept in memory. The row ends by 0.

I've written some code and every time I try to compile I get an error message saying that I'm missing a ";" right at the end of my `else`. Bizarre.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int max;
  int min;

  int nombre;

  printf("entrez un entier\n");
  scanf("%d", &nombre);
  max = min = nombre;
  while (nombre != 0) {
    if (nombre > max) {
      max = nombre;
    } else(nombre < min) {
      min = nombre;
    }
    printf("entrez un entier\n");
    scanf("%d", &nombre);
  }
  printf("le max est %d et le min est %d", max, min);
}
```

Comment: `else` is unconditional. You probably want `else if (...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The else statement doesn't take a condition. The statements within it are executed if and only if all the `if` and `else if` conditions before it are false. So, it don't take a condition itself.
So, you need to replace the `else` with an `else if` like that:

```
    if (nombre > max) {
      max = nombre;
    } else if(nombre < min) {
      min = nombre;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mohammed has [correctly identified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76741692/15261315) the cause of the problem, but a few extra notes.

First, `main` should return `int`.  `int main(...` rather than `void main(...`. While the void return is allowed, it is generally discouraged.

Second, you know `0` cannot occur in your input. So you could initialize `max` and `min` to `0` and then check for that and check for that to determine whether to set `max` and `min`.

You may also wish to use an unbounded loop and break from it when you detect the sentinel value. This lets you keep the `nombre` variable scoped to the loop.

We can error check the input by using `fgets` to read in a line and then `sscanf` to extract an integer. *If* `sscanf` doesn't return `1`, it did not succeed and we can print an error and go to the next loop iteration.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SENTINEL 0

int main(void) {
    int max = SENTINEL;
    int min = SENTINEL;

    for (;;) {
        printf("entrez un entier\n");

        char line[1024];
        int nombre;
        
        fgets(line, 1024, stdin);
        if (sscanf(line, "%d", &nombre) != 1) {
            printf("Enter a number, please.\n");
            continue;
        }

        if (nombre == SENTINEL) break;

        if (max == SENTINEL || nombre > max) {
            max = nombre;
        }
       
        if (min == SENTINEL || nombre < min) {
            min = nombre;
        }
    }

    printf("le max est %d et le min est %d\n", max, min);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "First, main should return int." --> C allows implementations to do otherwise.